# serverfault doesn't has a PM?

Tags: feature-request, serverfault

if I'm interested to send a private message to a certain user from serverfault, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

This has been discussed ad-nauseum on Meta Stack Overflow (where Stack Exchange itself is discussed) and has been declined (several times, if I recall correctly).

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) on MSO for excruciating detail.

Answer (score 5):

Server Fault does currently however have a chat room going on http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com .  If a person wants this sort of thing that is probably the place to go hang out (Closest you are going to get).

Comment: Of course that's of very limited use to those who work in different timezones.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: Pfft... only if you *sleep*...

Comment: @john but the chat room is stateful, so assuming there aren't thousands of messages per hour (depends on the room) hopefully people will be scrolling back and checking to answer.

Answer (score 3):

My take on this is that anyone who cares to be contacted has numerous ways to provide contact information for others to find. e.g. Email address or other details on their linked web site. Anyone not making themselves fairly easily found probably doesn't want to be contacted.